# NLog autoreload does not work

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I created a sample windows application to test NLog. I'm just writing all the message level inside a while loop (Trace, Debug, Warn & Error). I have set `autoReload='true'` and also specified  `minlevel="Debug"` in the NLog config file. This is working fine and printing all the messages.

I wanted to test the autoreload option and hence changed the minlevel to "Warn" manually in the config file to log only Warning messages while the application is running, but still all the messages are getting logged instead of logging only Warn and Error messages.

But if I restart the application, it takes from the config and prints only Warn and Error level messages. As far as my understanding based on the [link](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#automatic-reconfiguration), NLog should reload the config as and when it is changed and should start printing the logs based on the current config changes. Not sure what is wrong. Do I have to programatically reload the configuration? Please help. Following is my code,

**NLog.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log" >

  <targets>

    <target name="FileLogger" xsi:type="File" archiveAboveSize="1048576" fileName="Trace.log" archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"   />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="FileLogger" minlevel="Debug"  />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**LogMessage Code Snippet**

```
private void LogMessages(CancellationToken token)
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    logger.Debug("*********** Debug *************");
                    logger.Trace("----------- Trace --------------");
                    logger.Warn("~~~~~~~~~~~ Warn ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
                    logger.Error("========== Error =============");

                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

I was suspecting whether this is happening because of thread/task and started running directly from main thread, but still the problem persists. I also tried to enable NLog internal logging to see for any errors, but couldn't find anything suspicious.

Comment: How are you getting your `logger`?

Comment: Are you editing the config file in your project, or the one from the bin\Debug or bin\Release directory?

Comment: I was editing from the project. It was the dumb mistake. Thanks. It works when i edit from the Release directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [`LogManager.GlobalThreshold`](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.0.0/html/P_NLog_LogManager_GlobalThreshold.htm) property? Try doing that and don't forget to [`LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers()`](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.0.0/html/M_NLog_LogManager_ReconfigExistingLoggers.htm) afterwards

Comment: Thanks for providing me an answer. It was my mistake, I was editing from the project instead of release directory. Anyhow I'm not aware of the GlobalThreshold property. Will take a look.

Comment: Thats fine, but in production code if you want to dynamically change your logging config my answer is a better decision than modifying the config file.